# min3d on Android: how to background image

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, glsurfaceview

I need to set background image for my 3d scene.
I was using setZOrderOnTop(true) on my GLSurfaceView, and it was fine: underlying view background was visible under my 3d graphics.
But now I need to add a few views on top of my 3d graphics, so that made me use setZOrderOnTop(false), so now z indexes are fine, but background is black.
I've tried to set background drawable on GLSurfaceView, but in that case 3d scene renders **behind** the GLSurfaceView's background...
So, i think that there is an option to draw rectangle with background texture behind my scene. But i have no idea how to make it.

Comment: any luck to set Background image?